# What compiler shall I use for ruby and perl?

Tags: ruby, windows, perl, compiler-construction

I have recently started learning Ruby and Perl. Could any of you please suggest me compilers for those, so that I can practice?

Comment: You can practice without compilers.

Comment: Do you want a compiler (which can create stand-alone executables), an interpreter (which can run a script) or an interactive notebook user interface? For Ruby, I'd recommend `irb` as the user interface. See https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/

Comment: actually compiler, and also I am new to these languages. So I don't know any. :-) , pts

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: For Ruby and Perl it's not typical to use a compiler, and compilers have limitations which would distract you from learning the language. If you are a beginner, I'd recommend that you start using an interpreter or an interactive user interface. Search for *getting started perl* or *getting started ruby* in your favorite web search.

Comment: I use Windows 7,  leeduhem

Comment: http://strawberryperl.com/ for perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Perl you want [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) or [DWIM Perl](http://dwimperl.com/). Strawberry probably has everything you want but DWIM is just Strawberry with some extra modules and the Padre ide:

```
 It contains:

    Strawberry Perl 5.14.2.1 RC which itself is a standard Perl with several extensions already installed.
    A large part of Task::Kensho, a list of recommended packages.
    Padre, the Perl IDE 0.94.
    Module::Version 0.12 so you can use mversion to check which version of each module you have.
    Moose 2.0402, the post modern Object System.
    Dancer 1.3092 to build a light-weight web application.
    Plack and plackup 0.9985 to serve your web pages.
    Perl::Critic 1.117, to police yourself.
    Perl::Tidy 20101217, to keep your code nice.
    DateTime 0.72 to make it easy to deal with dates and time.
    SQLite 1.35, to hold your data tight.
    MySQL 4.020, PostgreSQL 2.18.1 and DBD::ODBC 1.31 drivers.
    Lots of additional modules... (see details in the README file.)
```